# How does a Connectionstring to a Oracle DB looks like?

Tags: c#, database, oracle, database-connection, connection-string

I need to connect to an Orace DB using C#.

I googled some times to get the Connectionstring and landed on this page:
https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

There I found this:

```
Source=MyOracleDB;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword; Security=no;
```

How can I define a Serveraddress in there ?

Comment: The answer is right there: If you do not want to rely on the host configuration in the ORACLE HOME tnsnames.ora, you can put it in the connection string [like this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-oracle/omiting-tnsnamesora/).

Comment: Alright ^^ thx this really confused me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the settings from the `tnsnames.ora` and use that to build an [EZConnect](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/network.112/e10836/naming.htm) connection string. Effectively, it looks like this one:

```
Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=portnumber))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sidOfTheService)));User ID=username;Password=pwd;
```

You see that the part after `Server` is the same as the configuration in your `tnsnames.ora`. After that, supply the username and password.